# XNA ContentLoadException

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm starting to learn "some" XNA and - as expected - I've run into an obstacle pretty early.

- I've created a WP7 XNA Game solution
- I've removed the default content project
- I've added my own content project "Sprites"
- I've added 3x *.png files to the "Sprites" project (MyImage1.png, MyImage2.png, MyImage3.png)
- I've added a Content reference, referencing the "Sprites" to the main game project

/**/

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    logoTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/MyImage1");

    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here    
}
```

I'm getting a ContentLoadException saying "not found" when trying to load one my *.png's

- I did check the output directory, a "Sprites" subfolder containing *.xnb files is present
- I did check the properties of the images, all are marked as Texture2Ds and have content importers and processors set to default XNA values

I'm pretty sure I'm making a common n00b'ish mistake, but I'm failing to see it, so I'd apreciate some guidance.

**Problem Fixed**

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; // The cause of the problem
```

Regards

Comment: Please mark `lukas` answer as correct rather than editing your answer.

Comment: @Neil I did find the answer sooner then he posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you remove the content project?

My guess is that you need to set the RootDirectory

```
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

which BTW creates ContentManager object.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following path formatting instead:

```
".\\Sprites\\MyImage1"
```

According to MSDN, the path must be relative to the current directory. And the directory separator is '\'.

Comment: I've re-examined the inner exception, it's trying to load the file from this path : "Error loading "Content\Sprites\MyImage1.xnb". File not found". The content isn't generated in a content subfolder, any idea why?

Comment: Yes, as @lukas mention, that is because you haven't set the 'RootDirectory'. Setting that property to "Sprites" and removing that part when loading the images should work.